# Does Ubuntu have a listed history of package updates?

Tags: package-management, updates

I would like to see how often a package has been updated in the past (for several packages). Slackware has a file listing all package updates: ftp://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/slackware/slackware64-current/ChangeLog.txt

Does Ubuntu have something similar?

If not, is there an easy way to get this information? I'm looking for an easier way than to dig through the package changelogs, if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/

you can also use the `apt-get changelog` command to get changelog for a single package

Comment: Is there also a way to view this information for a single release, say 14.04 LTS?

Comment: I don't know il it is possible to view for a single release, bur I've edited my answer if you want to know the changelog for a single package